# Data from service arent updated

Tags: angularjs, facebook

I'm very new to AngularJS and programming aswell, so it can be easy question for you but I'm struggling with it for plenty of hours and can't get my thinking straight.

So, my goal is simple, to have facebook login on my app (webpage), I'm using [Ciul angular-facebook module](https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook), this actually works but not in the way I want it. When user loggs I want to show his name and photo, but now I have to manually reload page, then it shows, until then it won't. Also I'm storing logged user into localStorage (works ok).

The problem is that after logging in the data aren't updated. In my html code I tried to call them from controller or service, but both had old data, and I don't know how to update it without reloading the page. The most interesting part is when I try it with simple variable and  it works like a charm.

Here is my Service

```
app.factory('mainService', ['$window', '$location', '$route', '$filter', 'Facebook', function (win, $location, $route, $filter, Facebook) {

    var scope = {
        fbLogin: false,
        fbUid: 0,
        fbAccessToken: 0,
        vkLogin: false
    };

    var user = {};
    if(localStorage.getItem('user') != null) {
        user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    } else {
        user = null;
    }

    return {
        scope : scope,
        user : user,
        fbLogin : function () {
            Facebook.login(function (response) {
                scope.fbLogin = response.status;
                scope.fbAccessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                scope.Uid = response.authResponse.userID;

                Facebook.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,picture', function (response) {
                    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response));
                });

            });   
            console.log('setting user');
                user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        },
        fbLogout : function () {
            Facebook.logout(function (response) {

            });
            user = null;
            localStorage.removeItem('user');
        },
        removeAuth : function () {
            Facebook.api({
                method: 'Auth.revokeAuthorization'
            }, function (response) {
                Facebook.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                    scope.fbLogin = response.status;
                });
            });
        }
    };


}]);
```

Here is my Controller

```
app.controller('IndexController', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', 'mainService', function ($scope, $location, $http, mainService) {

$scope.ms = mainService;

$scope.user = mainService.user;

$http({ 
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'backend/api/v1/getItems.php',
    headers: { "Content-Type": 'text/json; charset="utf-8"' }
})
    .success(function(data, status) {
        //alert("status is : "+status);
        if(status === 200) {
            $scope.items = data;
        }
    })
    .error(function(data, status) {
        $scope.items = [];
    });

}]);
```

Calling login function **< li >< a href="#/" ng-click="ms.fbLogin()">Login using Facebook**

Calling data in html **{{user.name}} or {{ms.user.name}}**

Well, the same problem is also with logging out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey so it's hard for me to say this is the exact problem but from the looks of it everything you have so far is actually pretty good.

There's only one problem I spot and it just boils down to understanding objects are bound to variables by reference. If you're not sure what that means I would say do some research on that first since it's a fundamental part of javascript.

What seems to be the problem here is that you are setting 'user' to an empty object in your service. In your controller you are then assigning $scope.user to that same object empty.

However in your login function you are assigning user to the new JSON from the storage. First, this should also be inside the success callback, right after you set the localstorage.

I'm not familiar with that module but I'm going to assume that those are async functions. Therefore you're grabbing that local storage data before it's even been set.

Also, by setting 'user' to a new object you have updated it's value in the service but **not** in the controller.

Because it's bound by reference, 'user' in the service now points to a **new** object, while $scope.user is still pointing to that **original empty object.**

To solve this problem you can do two things:

Handle the callback differently so that you reassign $scope.user to the new data.

Or you can take **advantage** of object reference.

You can keep most of your code the same, but in your service, instead of assigning the data to 'user', assign it to a **property on user**.

```
Facebook.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,picture', function (response) {
  localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response));
  user.data = response;
});
```

Since both the service and the controller are referencing the **same object**, you will have access to that new data property on $scope.user.

***HTML:***

```
<span>{{user.data.name}}</span>
```

Comment: Oh wow, that was easier than I thought, I'm so stupid. Thank you very much. Works like a charm!

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't feel dumb, it took me awhile to figure out that concept as well. Good luck!